# disabling combo box on selection of option of another combo box

Tags: php

I want to disable 2nd combo box if 1st combo box selection is the "formative" option. I would like to do it without refreshing the page and I am using PHP. Can anyone help?

P.S.: if the user selects the "submative" option, I want to get the 2nd combo box value in a variable as and when he/she chooses the option.

I am really stuck as I am new to PHP. If someone can help I will be grateful.

Below is the code:

```
echo'<select> <option valuet=" " selected="selected">Choose one</option>';
echo '<option valuet=1>formative</option>';
echo '<option valuet=2>Submative</option>';
echo "</select>";

$quizzes.... //query to get data from sql
echo'<select> <option valuer=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';
foreach($quizzes as $id2 => $name) 
{
echo "<option valuer=".$id2.">".$name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

**Edited: solved**

Thanks to everyone who helped me, you really solved my problem :)

Well this is the answer that solved my question for future use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#combo_1').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === '1'){
        $('#combo_2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        $('#combo_2').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

});
```

and in PHP:

```
echo '<select id="combo_1">'; 
echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Choose one</option>';
echo '<option value="1">formative</option>';
echo '<option value="2">Submative</option>';
echo '</select>';
$quizzes = $DB->get_records_menu('quiz', array('course' =>$courseid),'','id, name');
echo '<select id="combo_2">';
echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';

foreach($quizzes as $id2 => $name) {
  echo '<option value=' . $id2 . '>' . $name . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: If it should be done in page without refresh, it has nothing to do with PHP. You should look for Javascript solution.

Comment: this would not be made with php. You need to use javascript for that. I recommend to use jquery. With jquery this would be very easy

Comment: thats the issue i dont know jquery....

Comment: Ok, I fixed my code answer, try it now.

Comment: You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nd87/gm38F/

Comment: thanx NDLombradi 
it worked with some adjustments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JavaScript/jQuery solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#combo_1').change(function () {
        $('#combo_2').attr('disabled', (this.val() === '1' ? 'disabled' : ''));
    });

});
</script>
```

And change your PHP code as follows:

```
echo '<select id="combo_1">';
echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Choose one</option>';
echo '<option value="1">formative</option>';
echo '<option value="2">Submative</option>';
echo '</select>';

$quizzes.... //query to get data from sql
echo '<select id="combo_2">';
echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';

foreach($quizzes as $id2 => $name) {
     echo '<option value=' . $id2 . '>' . $name . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Try to be consistent in style; braces, quotation marks etc. stick to one, it will help you. And check your HTML against a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it helps to avoid bugs.

Comment: its saying missing inconditional expression at line
$('#combo_2').attr('disabled', (this.val() === '1' ? 'disabled' ? ''));

Comment: nvm corrected it with
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#combo_1').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === '1'){
            $('#combo_2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }else{
            $('#combo_2').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });

});

</script>

Comment: @stacymalina sorry, fixed that

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it in PHP straight, you can include the jQuery file in your page head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then write this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#my_sel').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === '1'){
            $('#second').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }else{
            $('#second').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

and change your php to this:

```
echo'<select id="my_sel"> <option valuet=" " selected="selected">Choose one</option>';
echo '<option valuet=1>formative</option>';
echo '<option valuet=2>Submative</option>';
echo "</select>";


$quizzes.... //query to get data from sql
echo'<select id="second"> <option valuer=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';
foreach($quizzes as $id2 => $name) 
{
echo "<option valuer=".$id2.">".$name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Test it [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nd87/gm38F/)

Comment: well it sure works, but i dont know why when i add it to moodle, it stops working any idea ?

Comment: https://moodle.org/
its an open source cms(lms)
and the problem has already been fixed, thankyou for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery library.

Try this:

```
echo'<select> <option valuet=" " onchange="change_select(this)" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';
echo '<option valuet=1>formative</option>';
echo '<option valuet=2>Submative</option>';
echo "</select>";


$quizzes.... //query to get data from sql
echo'<select name="second"> <option valuer=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';
foreach($quizzes as $id2 => $name) 
{
echo "<option valuer=".$id2.">".$name."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_select(args) {
            if ($(args).val() == "1") {
                $('[name="second"]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not seems to me really clear solution. It combines the pure javacript way with jquery access. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, this is how you could do it:

given in HTML:

```
<select id='firstSelect'><option>...</option></select>
<select id='secondSelect'><option>...</option></select>
```

this is the javascript:

```
$('#firstSelect').change(function(event){
  switch (event.target.value){
    case '1'://formative
      $('#secondSelect').disable();
      break;
    case '2'://submative
      var valueYouWant = $('#secondSelect').value;
    default:
      $('#secondSelect').enable();
  }
});
```

Comment: php is serverside scripting.  If you don't want to refresh or use ajax to go back to the php-side of your page, then you can't do it in php, and you'll need javascript.